# How to make a screen arrange by window size

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project. I have a screen with two horizontal DIV. The requirement is that when the window size is above 800px, both the divs will be visible. If it's below 800px,only 1 div will be visible.How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use Media Queries using CSS, where hdiv1 & hdiv2 are DIV Ids.

```
#hdiv1 {
    display: block;
    }
#hdiv2 {
    display: block;
    }

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

#hdiv1 {
    display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can probably be done using jQuery.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {  
if ( $(window).width() > 800){ 
    $( "YourDiv" ).show(); 
    $( "YourDiv" ).show(); 
} 

if ( $(window).width() < 800 ){ 
    $( "YourDiv" ).hide();
}

}
```

or you could add/remove css of for display from hidden to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of media query and display:none properties in CSS3.

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XuS4g/

```
#first,#second{
   height:400px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#first{
    width:70%;
}
#second{
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    #second{
        display:none;
    }
}
```